# CSS Rotation & IE: absolute positioning seems to break IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rotation, css-position

I'm trying to rotate a variety of text blocks so they are vertically oriented, and position them in very specific locations on a diagram which will be previewed and then printed.  CSS rotates the text very nicely in IE, FF, even Opera.

But when I try to position a rotated element, IE 7 & 8 (not worried about 6) breaks completely and the element stays in its original location.  Any way around this?  I really need to-the-pixel control of where these labels are located.

HTML

```
  <div class="content rotate">
    <div id="Div1" class="txtblock">Ardvark Avacado<br />Awkward</div>
    <div id="Div2" class="txtblock">Brownies<br />Bacteria Brussel Sprouts</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
div.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30px;
    border-top: black 4px solid; 
    border-right: blue 4px solid; 
    border-bottom: black 4px dashed; 
    border-left: blue 4px dashed; }

.rotate  {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); }

.txtblock {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    }

#Div1 {
    left:44px; 
    top:70px; 
    border:red 3px solid; }

#Div2 {
    left:13px; 
    top:170px; 
    border:purple 3px solid;  }
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide a live link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like an issue I spent a good deal of time with. I left two comments on Paul Irish's [blog post](http://paulirish.com/2010/introducing-css3please/) detailing my findings. Here is what I wrote:

> IE6 and 7: You must declare at least
>   height or width on the div that's
>   going to be be rotated BEFORE your
>   rotation filters appear in the CSS.
>   Even if you do this, however, any
>   styles applied to that div AFTER the
>   rotation filters appear in the code
>   will not be applied. The same seems to
>   be true for any styles applied to that
>   div's children as well. Weird.
>
> IE8: This seems to not be a problem. I
>   successfully applied styles to the div
>   (including declaring its height or
>   width for the first time) after the
>   rotation filters appear in the code.

...and more CSS rotation weirdness to report:

> In IE6 and 7, even if you follow the
>   rules I posted a few comments back,
>   you will still totally break your site
>   if you use more than one rotation
>   filter per external CSS file. You
>   either have to have separate CSS files
>   per rotation filter, or simply add
>   each filter nested in its own unique
>   style tags in the head of your html.
>   Failure to do so will only display the
>   first rotated object, but even this
>   will be blurry and at the incorrect
>   angle.
>
> Hilariously, removing the DOCTYPE
>   causes all the rotation to render
>   perfectly, so I'm assuming quirks mode
>   knows how to handle multiple rotation
>   filters? Also, with a larger, more
>   complex stylesheet, there were even
>   weirder side effects, but I couldn't
>   pinpoint what was causing those.
>   Anyways…
>
> Take home message:
>
> Use only 1 proprietary ms filter:
>   (when used for rotation, at least) per
>   external stylesheet. and.. Each
>   rotation filter in your html must be
>   in its own set of style tags.

Even though my issue was slightly different, you may be running into a similar situation with the two inner divs being rotated by the parent. It's worth a shot. At least try moving the .rotate delclaration to the bottom of the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Centrsource najboljše Ponudbe</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #content {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30px;
    border-top: black 4px solid; 
    border-right: blue 4px solid; 
    border-bottom: black 4px dashed; 
    border-left: blue 4px dashed; 
    }

.txtblock {
 display:block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div class="txtblock">Ardvark Avacado<br />Awkward</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

You're applying the code to the wrong element. Also as reference to others in understanding this http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Comment: Thanks, but it cascade down shouldn't it?  The children's position should be relative to their parent - that is, they should receive the same rotation.  And if I can't just rotate the parent I'd have to set the rotation for each child... and that's a tiresome list.

Comment: As far as I know filter: uses javascript as base to do all calculations so it's not really css - thus the cascade does not apply. Also IE has always had his way of handling things. 
P.s.: Mark as solved if this answers helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I find that this works if you put the rotations on the txtblocks, instead of on the outer container.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ilipo/2)

Comment: I tried this too.  The items rotate, but they are not displayed consistently between IE and FF.  I was rotating the container to try to get uniform positioning.  I did just see that IE7 seems to rotate absolutely positioned elements, and that it is IE8 is having trouble.